# syntax issue regarding to setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, button

May anyone explain to me this bit of code?

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
     }
});
```

In this case, `MainActivity` and `DetailActivity` are two classes I have created.

I am kind of confused,

1. In this case, what are the roles of `setOnClickListener` and `View.OnClickListener`?
2. Within the constructor method of the `Intent` class, for the context, why can't we just put `".this"` but we have to put in `MainActivity` class in the front? Under what kind of situation can we use `".this"`?

Answer (score 1):

1. `setOnClickListener` is a method. `View.OnClickListener` is an interface. The `setOnClickListener` method takes a `View.OnClickListener` as an argument. The syntax `new Foo() { ... }` defines an *anonymous inner class* instance that implements the interface `Foo`.
2. `this` refers to the instance, which in case of an inner class is the inner class `View.OnClickListener` instance. You can refer to the outer class instance (an activity which is-a `Context`) by scoping the reference with the outer class name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `MainActivity.this` because the `setOnClickListener` is a interface in a `View class` and it contains a method `onClick(View v);` , if you will use this instead of `MainActivity.this`, it will refer to the Context of `OnClickListener`, when we specify `MainActiviy.this` it refers to the Context of `MainActivity` class. This concept is called **Shadowing** in java.

Comment: In a greater depth, may I ask what is setOnClickListener for in this case? and how do we manage to know (.this) referring to which context in other situation?

Comment: SetOnClickListener is a interface and the way it is used is called Anonymous inner class, we don't want to intercept the event of OnClickListener we have to intercept the event of Activity that's why we are using MainActivity.this not 'this'